# Scala - Multiple ways of initializing containers

Tags: scala, containers

I am new to Scala and was wondering what is the difference between initializing a Map data structure using the following three ways:

```
 private val currentFiles: HashMap[String, Long] = new HashMap[String, Long]()
 private val currentJars = new HashMap[String, Long]
 private val currentVars = Map[String, Long]
```

Comment: Your second and third statement does not work you need () at the end: private val currentJars = new HashMap[String, Long]()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` and `HashMap` are almost equivalent, but not exactly the same thing.

[Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map) is trait, and [HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) is a class. Although under the hood they **may** be the same thing (scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) (more on that later).

When using

```
private val currentVars = Map[String, Long]()
```

You get a `Map` instance. In scala, `()` is a sugar, under the hood you are actually calling the `apply()` method of the [object Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map$). This would be equivalent to:

```
private val currentVars = Map.apply[String, Long]()
```

Using

```
private val currentJars = new HashMap[String, Long]()
```

You get a HashMap instance.

In the third statement:

```
private val currentJars: HashMap[String, Long] = new HashMap[String, Long]()
```

You are just not relying anymore on [type inference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html). This is **exactly the same** as the second statement:

```
private val currentJars: HashMap[String, Long] = new HashMap[String, Long]()
private val currentJars = new HashMap[String, Long]() // same thing
```

## When / Which I use / Why

About type inference, I would recommend you to go with type inference. IMHO in this case it removes verbosity from the code where it is not really needed. But if you really miss like-java code, then include the type :) .

Now, about the two constructors...

### Map vs HashMap

**Short answer**

You should probably always go with `Map()`: it is shorter, already imported and returns a trait (like a java interface). This last reason is nice because when passing this Map around you won't rely on implementation details since `Map` is just an interface of what you want or need.

On the other side, `HashMap` *is* an implementation.

**Long answer**

`Map` is not always a `HashMap`.

As seen in *Programming in Scala*, `Map.apply[K, V]()` can return a different class depending on how many key-value pairs you pass to it ([ref](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html#tab:default-maps)):

```
Number of elements       Implementation

0                        scala.collection.immutable.EmptyMap

1                        scala.collection.immutable.Map1 

2                        scala.collection.immutable.Map2

3                        scala.collection.immutable.Map3

4                        scala.collection.immutable.Map4 

5 or more                scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
```

When you have less then 5 elements you get an special class for each of these small collections and when you have an empty Map, you get a singleton object.

This is done mostly to get better performance.

You can try it out in repl:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

val m2 = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
m2.isInstanceOf[HashMap[Int, Int]]
// false

val m5 = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 6)
m5.isInstanceOf[HashMap[Int, Int]]
// true
```

If you are really curious you can even take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6ed701004550fa04b8ac2d3419f2ea4141c834ad/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L120).

So, even for performance you should also probably stick with `Map()`.

Comment: Well, you bet they are not the same. Question asked for a description of how the initializations are different, and not the verification of the fact that they are not same.

Comment: Sorry didn't know. Thought by your answer you thought they were doing the same thing. Anyway, updated the answer. I don't know exactly what info do you want. Could you update the answer with this?

Comment: minor correction: `private val currentVars = Map.apply[String, Long]()` - the type parameters go on the method, not the object.

Comment: What kind of Map would an apply function on Map yield. And what are the particular use cases/benefits of initializing containers in the different ways mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different parts to your question.

first, the difference between using an explicit type or not (cases 1 and 2) goes for any class, not necessarily containers.

```
 val x = 1
```

Here the type is not explicit, and the compiler will try to figure it out using type inference. The type of `x` will be `Int`.

```
val x: Int = 1
```

Same as above, but now explicitly. If whatever you have at the right of `=` can't be cast to an Int, you will get a compiler error.

```
val x: Any = 1
```

Here we will still store a `1`, but the type of the variable will be a parent class, using polymorphism.

---

The second part of your question is about initialization. The base initialization is as in java:

```
val x = new List[Int]()
```

This calls the class constructor and returns a new instance of the exact class.
Now, there is a special method called `.apply` that you can define and call with just parenthesis, like this:

```
val x = Seq[Int]()
```

This is a shortcut for this:

```
val x = Seq.apply[Int]()
```

Notice this is a function on the `Seq` object. The return type is whatever the function wants it to be, it is just another function. That said, it is mostly used to return a new instance of the given type, but there are no guarantees, you need to look at the function documentation to be sure of the contract.

That said, in the case of `val x = Map[String, Long]()` the implementation returns an actual instance of `immutable.HashMap[String, Long]`, which is kind of the default `Map` implementation.

Comment: Note that Map does not always return an HashMap instance (see my answer).

Comment: True, but maps with sizes 0-5 are kind of corner cases and those small optimizations don't change the contracts of map trait, immutability, or even overall performance (as in [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)). Still useful though, thanks for pointing it out.